# finding number of occurrences of a sub_string in another string

Tags: python-3.x

```
string = 'WoW!ItSCoOWoWW'
sub_string = 'oW'
count = 0

st = list(string)


for x in range(len(st)):
    if ord(string[x]) == ord(sub_string[0]):
        s1 = ''.join(string[x:])
        if sub_string in s1:

            count +=1
print(count)
```

**Problem:**
     ord() function can't distinguish between 'o' and 'O'(in string).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have misplaced the parentheses `print(ord(string[x]), ord(sub_string)`
Update this line to fix your code:

```
print(ord(string[x]), ord(sub_string))
```

Comment: You also need the index entry on that line - `print(ord(string[x]), ord(sub_string[0]))`

Answer (score 0):

There's a builtin function for that: `str.count()`

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_count.htm

The issue with your code is in the `print` statement just before the error line. You're missing a parentheses.

Comment: count() doesn't work in the case of string as in the above edited code.